# Include static libraries into dynamic library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries

We have a dynamic library that is developed in a discontinued tool (Borland Kylix), so we have to do it in a Red Hat 7.2 installation. Until now, we hadn't any problems loading this library (libX.so) in subsequent versions of Linux. However, in the most recent versions, like Fedora 21, we get a segmentation fault signal when trying to load the library using `dlopen`. We have tried some alternatives and one of them is to link the old static libraries into this shared lib.

We know that this is not the best approach and we should trust the backwards compatibility provided by the linux kernel and its system libs, but in our case (unless we are doing something wrong), it is not working.

So, how can we statically link the system libraries into an existing shared library? We need to use the already compiled `libX.so` and "plug in" into it the static system libraries like `libc.a`. We have already done it using the Kylix link tool (`ilink`), but it generated an invalid library. So, we want to use `ld` or `gcc` to pick this `libX.so` and generate another `libX.so` containg the static libraries.

Edited: included gdb output.

```
Program recevied signal SIGSEV, Segmentation Fault. 
0xb7fe7c72 in _dl_relocate_object () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried to debug the segfault? If you install the debug symbols of the loader, you might at least get a stack trace which would help get you the reason for the fault.

Anyway, more to your question, you might be getting errors due to problems in the loader versions. You can try "patchelf" (https://nixos.org/patchelf.html) to change loader version and library paths to possibly get around the page fault.

Comment: Thanks. I've included the gdb output and I will try "patchelf".